# Find text in Table or column

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I have a table with column `dbo.tb_item_description`. Inside of that I would like to find the string 'For North America Only' .

Comment: In a certain column or in any column?

Comment: Show us [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258228%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).